# Editing Panels in Admin Theme

Tags: panels

I would like to edit my Panels (Panel Layout and Panel Content) in the administration theme, however when I click on the tab to go to panel layout (node/%node/panel_layout), it always opens in my default theme.

Is there a way to have it use my admin theme for panels?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a small custom module and use [`hook_admin_paths()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7):

```
function MYMODULE_admin_paths() {
  return array(
    'node/*/panel_layout' => TRUE
  );
}
```

This will instruct Drupal to treat paths that match the pattern as admin pages, including rendering them with the admin theme.

Comment: I've edited the example provided because it didn't work as originally written.  The path needs to be the key with a value of `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Please install "Pahe Theme" module, add admin theme in it and then add node/*/panel_layout* path in it.